# Automatically categorize downloads?

Tags: finder, filesystem, finder-tag

Usually, when I download something, I need to take a template action on it, depending on the file type. Mp3 files get imported to iTunes, wav and rex files to the sample folders, zips get unzipped (and then are going through this procedure recursively), doc files are moved to documents, dmg files mounted, installed and discarded, and so on. But usually, I forget about some of the files, or use them without moving to a more relevant place, and my Download folder gets very crowded as a result.

Is there a tool that would help me move downloaded files to the relevant folders depending on their type?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [**Hazel**](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel):

> #### Create rules to automatically keep your files organized
>
> Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically organizing your files according to the rules you create. It features a rule interface similar to that of Apple Mail so you should feel right at home. Have Hazel move files around based on name, date, type, what site/email address it came from (Safari and Mail only) and much more. Automatically put your music in your Music folder, movies in Movies.

> [image]